# get strings that are in List<String> excluding strings in List<String[]>

Tags: c#

How would I go about getting all the strings that appear in `List<string>` except for the strings that appear in `List<string[]>`. I can get this to work if they are both `List<string>` by doing

```
IEnumerable<string> list3 = List1.Except(List2);
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it using `List<string[0]>` in place of `list2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `SelectMany` to flatten `List<string[]>` into a single `IEnumerable<string>`. Assuming `list2` is of type `List<string[]>`, you can do:

```
var list3 = list1.Except(list2.SelectMany(x=>x));
```

However, if you just want the first `string[]` in `List<string[]>` then, assuming that there is at least one entry in the list, you could do:

```
var list3 = list1.Except(list2.First());
```

**Additional**
`list2.SelectMany(x=>x)` is equivalent to:

```
var flattenedList2 = from x in list2
                     from y in x
                     select x;
```

Comment: This appears to work, but I have almost no idea what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe: In this case `SelectMany` takes each `string[]` and combines their contents. It's equivalent to `from x in list2 from y in x select x`.